# Bootstrap not working inside Outlook 365 Deployed Office Add-in

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, office365, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to implement Bootstrap 3 Tabs in an App for Office but I keep getting the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at line 1453, column 2 in https://localhost:44303/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #profile&_xdm_Info=null|null|null
```

Based on that it seems like Outlook 365 is appending `&_xdm_Info=null|null|null` but I don't understand why, how, or what to do about it if true.

Here is a whole simplified `Home.html` to illustrate the issue.  Note it will work fine is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jofrysutanto/K9LpL/3/) or [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IIbHBAMBgr).

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title></title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content-main">
    <!--<div class="padding">-->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id='content' class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <ul>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>home</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <ul>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
                <li>profile</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is my call stack -->

```
    Sizzle.error [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 1453    Script
    Sizzle.tokenize [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 2067 Script
    Sizzle.select [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 2474   Script
    Sizzle [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 850   Script
    find [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 2690    Script
    jQuery.fn.init [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 2798  Script
    jQuery [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 76    Script
    Tab.prototype.show [bootstrap.js] Line 2050 Script
    Anonymous function [bootstrap.js] Line 2123 Script
    each [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 374 Script
    jQuery.prototype.each [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 139    Script
    Plugin [bootstrap.js] Line 2118 Script
    clickHandler [bootstrap.js] Line 2147   Script
    jQuery.event.dispatch [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 4429   Script
    elemData.handle [jquery-2.1.3.js] Line 4115 Script
```

Comment: Hey Paladin, I'm guessing that the &xdm_Info bit is being added when you try to navigate to the different tab, correct?

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to figure out how I overcome that since it seems to be a part of the Apps for Office "framework"....

Comment: Regardless, hashtag navigation is pretty common nowadays and it should be a supported scenario. Let me check if we have a bug and get back to you.

Comment: I've done some investigation into the matter, and we do add the &xdm_Info=* specifically to the URL fragment identifier (hashtag parameters) on navigation. That is indeed a part of the framework. However, putting key-value pairs into fragment identifier using & is valid, so I'm wondering if there's a bug in Bootstrap tabs or jQuery that cannot parse key-value pairs in fragment identifier. To help further look into this, could you provide us with a stack trace of the error?

Comment: Sure, should I add it to this post or should I send it to you directly?

Comment: I think you should probably edit the original post so that if I fall off the face of the earth someone else can help you instead :)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  I added my call stack, hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you try this for me: instead of <a href="#profile">, try <a data-target="#profile"> and see if that still causes the same error. If it fixes the problem, I'll compile my findings into an answer with more context.

Comment: Interesting, that did it.  I look forward to the explanation and I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can work around this issue by using `<a data-target="#profile">` instead of `<a href="#profile">`

**Explanation:** The Apps for Office framework relies on the office.js that is loaded from the app to communicate cross-frame with the host application (like Outlook). In order to preserve some states across page navigation, we append some information as URL fragment (like _xdm_Info) so that the second page of the app can talk to the host application as well.

Meanwhile, Bootstrap uses `<a>` tags to navigate between tags, which is obviously the tag used for navigation used in HTML. From on here, I'll be honest and say I'm guessing a little bit, but it seems like for whatever reason, we are modifying the href attribute of the `<a>` tags from the app to insert the state information as URL fragment.

From Bootstrap's tab.js:

```
Tab.prototype.show = function () {
    var $this    = this.element
    var $ul      = $this.closest('ul:not(.dropdown-menu)')
    var selector = $this.data('target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
}
```

As you can see here, the selector that the logic uses to display the tab is first trying to get the `data-target` attribute from the clicked tab selector, and then falls back to trying to use the `href` attribute. From the error you attached, when it falls back to the `href` attribute, the value of that attribute is `#profile&_xdm_Info=null|null|null` instead of just `#profile`. This is why when `var $target = $(selector)` is run, jQuery's selector engine, Sizzle, complains because that is not a valid CSS selector.

This is why the problem is eliminated by using the `data-target` attribute instead. I believe that since it is not an attribute traditionally used for navigation, we don't muck with it.

**Follow-up:** I'm going to confirm that this is by design and not a bug, and that there is no better way to append `_xdm_Info` to the URL fragment. IIRC, Bootstrap is not the only Javascript/jQuery plugin that uses the `href` attribute to communicate CSS selectors to code, and we should try to enable this scenario instead of encouraging developers to work around it. If this is indeed the only way to accomplish this, I'll push to have this included in the documentation.

**EDIT:** I've followed up with the team that builds the Apps for Office framework about this issue. It seems that indeed altering the href attributes of anchor tags in the app was part of the design. However, the discussion on whether this was the right way to do it is moot because they have moved away from this design - new versions of office.js will no longer do this, so hopefully this will not block any other scenarios going forward.

Comment: This is quite possibly the most helpful answer I personally have ever received here on SO!  Can't thank you enough for your time, efficiency, and transparency.  I'd be fascinated to hear the results of your "Follow-up".  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the compliment!